# sql query to determine the most similar goods by tags

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i'm making an e-store, so i have 3 tables:

1) `goods`

```
id      | title
--------+----------- 
1       | Toy car
2       | Toy pony
3       | Doll
```

2) `tags`

```
id      | title
--------+----------- 
1       | Toy
2       | Boys
3       | Girls
```

3) `links`

```
goods_id| tag_id
--------+----------- 
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 2
2       | 3
3       | 3
```

so i need to print related goods using such an algorithm: get the goods which are most similar to selected item using tags. the most tags are mutual - the most suitable the item is

so the result for the `goods#1` should be: `goods#2`,`goods#3`

for the `goods#2`: `goods#1`,`goods#3`

for the `goods#3`: `goods#2`,`goods#1`

and i have no idea how can i get the similar goods sorted by count of mutual tags with one query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return all items that have the maximum number of tags in common:

```
SET @item = 1;

SELECT
  goods_id
FROM
  links
WHERE
  tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM links WHERE goods_id=@item)
  AND goods_id!=@item
GROUP BY
  goods_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      links
    WHERE
      tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM links WHERE goods_id=@item)
      AND goods_id!=@item
    GROUP BY
      goods_id
    ORDER BY
      COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fb60/1).

Or this one will return all items, even those with no tags in common, ordered by the number of tags in common desc:

```
SELECT
  goods_id
FROM
  links
WHERE
  goods_id!=@item
GROUP BY
  goods_id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(CASE WHEN tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM links WHERE goods_id=@item) THEN 1 END) DESC;
```

Comment: Nice tool! I didn't know fiddle. It will be very useful for me, thanks for posting.

Comment: thanks! but it returns only the first similar item in the fiddle... not all

Comment: your query is good but if we cut the second part it works better, check out, this is working better as far as i can see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fb60/8/0

Comment: @dimaninc pls have a look at my updated query, i'm not sure but maybe you are looking for my last query

Comment: i use the case that in my sqlfiddle link, works perfect. thanks a lot for help, buddy!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to show the goods with goods id = 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  goods.*
FROM
  goods
  LEFT JOIN links ON links.goods_id = goods.id
WHERE links.tag_id IN (SELECT links.tag_id 
                       FROM links
                       WHERE links.goods_id = 2)
```

when you did not include goods_id = 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  goods.*
FROM
  goods
  LEFT JOIN links ON links.goods_id = goods.id
WHERE links.goods_id != 2 AND links.tag_id IN (SELECT links.tag_id 
                       FROM links
                       WHERE links.goods_id = 2)
```

can see on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fb60/38

Answer (score -1):

Some help:

Assuming you are looking the most similar to goods#1

```
SELECT a.*  
FROM (SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id <> 1) a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT z.goods_id, count(*) as total
          FROM links z
          WHERE z.goods_id <> 1 AND
          z.tag_id in (SELECT DISTINCT tag_id from links where goods_id = 1)
          GROUP BY z.goods_id) b 
ON a.id = b.goods_id
ORDER by b.total DESC
```

However, I think you can try something a bit different. Instead of ordering by the number of common tags, you can sort by the ratio of common tags. With this you will avoid the fact that the products with more tags will appear always at the top of the rankings, even if the relative common tags are not many.